# Замена IP пользователей

Tags: ip, usercontrol

Используем ресурс, который не принимает пользователей из определенный ГЕО. Возможно ли менять IP пользователей на IP страны из "белого списка" и передавать их с уже подменёнными IP?

Comment: Можно, подменяйте. Надеюсь, у вас есть некий сервис (прокси-сервер, VPN-сервер, прочее) с IP "из белого списка", способный выполнить такую подмену? вот через него и работайте.

Comment: либо пользователям использовать прокси из белого списка. либо вам сами проксировать запросы пользователей. задачу следует описать более конкретно. не ясно, что имеется в виду под "используем ресурс"

Comment: Akina, teran, благодарю за помощь, сейчас попробую. Разве это так просто?) Не нужно писать скрипт какой-то или применять библиотеки?

Comment: У вас должен быть в распоряжении IP "из белого списка", на котором можно организовать такую подмену (какой-нить забугорный VPS/VDS), либо купленный прокси/VPN-сервис на таком адресе (ну и соответственно настройки, установка клиента или что там надо для конкретной технологии). А если нету, тогда только free proxy - само собой без гарантий. Локальные библиотеки тут ничем не помогут.

Comment: Akina, а можно динамичные IP использовать нужного ГЕО использовать в таком случае?